# What are the recommended paper size requirements for printing professional documents (Plain A4/Letterhead/Bond Paper)?

Tags: professionalism, human-resources, india, relieving-letter, documentation

Recently I came across one of my friend's experiences while he was under his notice period with the HR manager of the company. I need an HR professional's advice or people with good knowledge on the same.

Here is the incident:

The relieving letter and the experience certificates were **printed out on a normal, low-quality A4 sized paper**, and that's not even on a pre-printed company letter pad (Letterhead).

Many of his friends working in other firms abroad and local, advised him **it's better to get it printed on the company Letterhead using bond excel papers**.

Can anyone working in the HR provide some recommendations regarding this?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk given many posts on here about relieving letters, then India is most likely...

Comment: A country tag maybe helpful here.

Answer (score 10):

In many of the cases, these documents are provided as soft-copies, and not necessarily in a printed version.

In my experience, what matters is the authenticity of the document, since this is not  to serve as a proper *legal* document per se (rather, an informational one), it really does not matter what type of material is used for a printed copy.

If and when challenged / inquired (example: background check), it should be possible to establish the correctness of the information - that's all matters.